# ASP.NET page load event why are the items not getting added to the dropdownlist control

Tags: asp.net

In the Page_Load event of an ASP.NET webform, without checking if it is Postback event, I am adding two items to a DropdownList control. I expected each time I refresh the webpage those two items ("Male" , "Female") will be added to the dropdownlist control. But I only see "Male" and "Female" items added to the dropdownlist control.

```
     using System;
     using System.Collections.Generic;
     using System.Linq;
     using System.Web;
     using System.Web.UI;
     using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

     namespace WebApplication1
     {
public partial class Dropdownlist : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DropDownList1.Items.Add("Male");
        DropDownList1.Items.Add("Female");


    }

    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write(DropDownList1.Text);

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not refresh the page manually. Try changing dropdown values and note

more on Ispostback [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [Page Life cycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)

when you refresh only dropdown will have 2 values as your dropdown will be initialized

if you now change your dropdown from UI (dont manually refresh) or any button clicks then you should see 4 as pageload will be called. number might increase as you do each event

Hope this helps.